# Solve Implicit Matrix Equation Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a question (probably silly), which I'm not able to answer.

Consider three matrices A, B and M. All of them are NxN matrices and 
I also know that A and B are symmetric (they are covariance matrices).

I need to numerical find the matrix **M** from the following equation **B = M A M^{T}**, using python.
In other words, how can I solve for an implicit matrix equation **using python**?

This is my attempt with fsolve:

```
import scipy
import scipy.optimize
f = lambda M: (np.mat(B)-(np.mat(M)*np.mat(A)*np.mat(M.T)))
M0 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(f, np.identity(57))
```

I gave as initial guess the identity matrix.

**Problem:**

```
/Users/Simone/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.pyc in __mul__(self, other)
    339         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    340             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 341             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    342         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    343             return N.dot(self, other)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I have tried also in a different way:

```
f = lambda X: ((B) - np.dot(X,np.dot(A,X.T)))  
X0 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(f, np.identity(57))
```

Again, "matrices are not aligned". It is kinda impossible because my are all nxn square matrices and none of the operations I have done changes the dimensions.
Of course I checked

```
B.shape, 
A.shape, 
np.identity.(57).shape 
((B) - np.dot(X,np.dot(A,X.T))).shape
```

And they are all the same!

Thank you so much,
Simone

Comment: Have you tried to do this by yourself?

Comment: No, I don't know how to work with matrix expression like this.

Comment: I recommend you to look at numPy library. There are many mathematical functions you can use.

Comment: You'll get better support for this question if you at least post some details about the algorithm you want to implement. If your concern is how to solve that equation analytically, there's a Math Stack Exchange site. If there is something about Python's syntax that makes this algorithm difficult to implement, edit your question to include the relevant code you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I have posted my attempt as you suggested.